# implement user avatar composed with dropdown using BootstrapVue

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Vue2 and styled with BootstrapVue
What I want to implement looks like below:
[image]

However, I tried myself and even looked up example in [document](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown#button-content) ,
I have no idea why the result is vertical align(I thought it would be horizontal align by default).

[image]

Here's part of my html code

```
<b-navbar-nav>
  <b-nav-item-dropdown text="User" left clas="user">
      <template #button-content>
        <div class="profile">
          <b-icon icon="person-fill"></b-icon>
        </div>
        <p>Username</p>
      </template>

      <b-dropdown-item>
        <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
      </b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>
        <router-link to="/register">Register</router-link>
      </b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>
        <router-link to="/logout">Logout</router-link>
      </b-dropdown-item>
   </b-nav-item-dropdown>
</b-navbar-nav>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/binbon_4412/c78z9fgr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you need to wrap your content in `b-row` so that it won't overflow. This is working for me:

```html
<b-nav-item-dropdown text="User" left clas="user" no-caret>
      <template #button-content>
        <b-row>
          <div class="profile">
            <b-icon icon="person-fill"></b-icon>
          </div>
          <p>Username</p>
          <b-icon icon="caret-down-fill"></b-icon>
        </b-row>
      </template>

      <b-dropdown-item>
        <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
      </b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>
        <router-link to="/register">Register</router-link>
      </b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>
        <router-link to="/logout">Logout</router-link>
      </b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```